# How to avoid this duplication of code? I wanted to repeat the same code 25 times

Tags: javascript, html

I didn't want to repeat the same code 25 times in the part of "getElementById", "carregaItem(iVid)" and " < div id="item"> < /div> ". The BDVYT array has 25 elements I just put 2 for simplicity. There must be some way to do it but I'm not getting there.

```js
var BDVYT = [{durac:27},{durac:23},];

refItem = document.getElementById("item");
refItem2 = document.getElementById("item2");

function inic(){
    mostraItem();
}

function mostraItem(){
    carregaItem(0);
    carregaItem1(1);
    //-----------
   //until carregaItem24(24)
}

function carregaItem(iVid){
    var codHTML = "";
    codHTML += '<div id="itemInfo">';
    codHTML += 'duração: <b>' + duracVid(iVid) + 'minutos</b>';
    codHTML += '</div>';
    
    refItem.innerHTML = codHTML;
}

function carregaItem1(iVid){
    var codHTML = "";
    codHTML += '<div id="itemInfo2">';
    codHTML += 'duração: <b>' + duracVid(iVid) + 'minutos</b>';
    codHTML += '</div>';
    
    refItem2.innerHTML = codHTML;
}

//until carregaItem24(iVid)

function duracVid(iVid){
    return BDVYT[iVid].durac;
}
```

```html
<body onload="inic()">

    <div id="item"></div>
    <div id="item2"></div>

</body>
```

Comment: Instead of using 24 IDs, use one class. That's what classes are for :) `<div class="itemInfo">'`, select them all with `querySelectorAll('.itemInfo')`, loop over the results etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use classes for the `refItem`s instead, and when iterating over the collection of them, use the index being iterated over to find the associated element in the `BDVYT` array.

```js
var BDVYT = [{durac:27},{durac:23},];
const refItems = document.querySelectorAll('.item');
refItems.forEach((item, i) => {
  item.innerHTML = `
    <div id="itemInfo2">
      duração: <b>${BDVYT[i].durac} minutos</b>
    </div>
    `;
});
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
</body>
```